# Python Game Server Script Error - Magnitude_Squared

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to python and am trying to create a server for a small game called Cube World. As the game is fairly under-developed the (rather small) community has to create most of the content ourselves (as far as PvP). [This](https://github.com/matpow2/cuwo-scripts/blob/master/koth/scripts/kingofthehill.py) is the original script that I am trying to use but has presented some issues. Since I am quite new I have asked many questions over on r/learnpython but less and less people are able to provide a useful answer. The changes I have made to the original script are as follows:

**Line 16:**

```
import pygame

vec = pygame.math.Vector3

a = vec(1, 1, 1)

print(a.magnitude_squared())
```

**Line 386:**

```
for player in players:

player.position = pygame.math.Vector3

distance = (self.event_location -
                        player.position).magnitude_squared()
```

I was advised on Reddit to use pygame to fix the magnitude_squared issue. While it seems to have fixed some of the code I still have some issues. I typically get the error *no attribute named Magnitude_Squared* but in this current script, I get *TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation* on line 389 *(self.event_location - player.position).magnitude_squared()*. If anyone can provide any assistance or advice that would be great. (Keep in mind I know very little about how to use python)

Comment: Are you using pygame just to use its `magnitude_squared` function? It seems to Cube Worlds already uses pyrr's vector classes.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was told, I have seen this script work on old servers and apparently, pyrr doesn't support the magnitude_squared function. As I don't really understand the script that well I don't know any other way.

Comment: Then for the love of god stop using pygame. Who gives you such a shitty advise? Write a magnitude_squared function yourself: it's just `vector.x ** 2 + vector.y ** 2 + vector.z ** 2`.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have implemented it properly by just replacing all magnitude_squared() with this instead. I now get the problem Vector3 has no attribute vector.

Answer (score 0):

`TabError` comes from the fact that you cannot use spaces and tabs when indenting lines in Python 3, just stick with using 4 spaces per indent (you can set your editor to make Tab key insert 4 spaces).

`AttributeError` *probably* comes from the issue that you should call the `magnitude_squared` function like this;

```
print(magnitude_squared(a))
```

Instead of this;

```
print(a.magnitude_squared())
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have made the change to the attribute error. As for the TabError I now get the same problem, on the same line, but on the final bracket after magnitude_squared. I feel like I probably am missing something simple just not sure what.

Comment: @P3nguin33 Your line, (I think it's 389) should look like this: `distance = magnitude_squared(self.event_location - player.position)`

Comment: With this, I still get the TabError for the final bracket.

Comment: @P3nguin33 Note that use of an IDE, such as Visual Studio code, will normally take care of indentation for you.

Comment: I'm only using notepad++ because I didn't actually expect to have to spend so much time on it.